# Can I implement local mobile banking in my app rather than google billing as payment

Tags: android, google-play

I am from Bangladesh and have small startup company. Basically we build app and market them locally. Recently we plan to sell our app's multi digital feature to the user. As google play policy, "digital goods need to sell by google billing". We than start study about it. In our country, google merchant account is possible, so we can implement google billing as payment method.

But problem is, google won't accept payment from any mobile banking or bank account service from our country, only duel currency credit card. Only less than 0.1% has credit card in our country. And another thing, my user maximum lives in villages, without mobile banking how they actually pay us?

So, can I implement local mobile banking in my app rather than google billing as payment. If google accept minimum one mobile banking system in my country, I will happy to use google billing. We only want to distribute my app inside my country right now.